# value of a variable reusing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io

I have following controllers

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateDirectory(string product_ID , string type)
{
   .......

 return Json("OK");

}

[HttpPost]
public ContentResult UploadFiles(string folderid, string foldertype)
{
  .........
}
```

and using following script I'm trying to call and pass parameters to `CreateDirectory` controller method and `UploadFiles` controller method

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var productid = "sample";

    $('#idd').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home")',
            data: { product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val(), type: "type1" },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",            
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === 'OK')
                {
                    productid = $('#Product_ID').val();
                    alert(productid)
                }
                else
                    alert("errro");
            }
        });
    });  

  $("#idd").fileinput({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        uploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Home")',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        overwriteInitial: true,
        uploadExtraData: { folderid : productid , foldertype : "type1" },            

    });   

</script>
```

**Issue**:

I'm assigning new value for `var productid` in click JavaScript event of above script.

like this `productid = $('#Product_ID').val();`

then I try to reuse that newly assigned value for `productid` reuse/reassign in `fileinput` JavaScript event

like this `folderid : productid`

but I cannot see newly assigned value for `folderid` , when Its calling to `UploadFiles` method I can see `folderid` is value is `sample`

Comment: research the term closure w.r.t javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX i cannot understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#idd` is a file input, and both `.click()` and `.fileinput()` are both called when the element is clicked, your problem is that `.fileinput()` does not wait for the AJAX (mind the first A: Asynchronous) call of `click()` to return and modify `productid`.

Make sure that your `.ajax()` is called AND finished before calling `.fileinput()`.

You could move the `.fileinput()` code to the success function of `.ajax()` to accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah ! you're correct , I want to call `.fileinput()` after `click()` event with its modified values. but as you said once I put this `.fileinput()` inside success event of  `click()` its disappearing this plugin :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in the ajax call. By the time you make the round-trip to the controller and back to the success, the value of $('#Product_ID').val(); will be null or empty string, assume it is a value from a text box, the content of the text box would have cleared.

Change it as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var productid = "sample";

    $('#productId').click(function () {

     var myProductId = $('#Product_ID').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home")',
            data: { product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val(), type: "type1" },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",            
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === 'OK')
                {
                    productid = myProductId; 
                    alert(productid)
                }
                else
                    alert("errro");
            }
        });
    });  

  $("#fileinput").fileinput({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        uploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Home")',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        overwriteInitial: true,
        uploadExtraData: { folderid : productid , foldertype : "type1" },            

    });   

</script>
```

Comment: Nope Once I use your approach, In the `UploadFiles` method I'm getting `folderid` value as `sample` ,

Comment: I did not understand your comment. Did the approach work or not. Looking at you code again I notice you have the same selector   $('#idd') for both the click and fileinput. They should be different

Comment: nope its not working , actually `click` function I'm using to create a directory , `fileinput` function I'm using to upload files

Comment: Please look at your ids . They are the same. I don't think they should be same